# Getting multiple table view instances to match

Tags: user-interface, uitableview, uistoryboard, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to get the cells returned within my `searchResultsTableView` to look just like those in the "regular", non-search table view. Here's my [regular view](http://cl.ly/image/1q2d2n0Q2h0g).

The first time you search, the results are styled exactly like the "regular" table view. However, once you you cancel the searchDisplayController and tap the Search button again, [you'll get this](http://cl.ly/image/3n0D2Z3U030i).

It looks to me like the background isn't being set after the first time the search display controller is loaded.

I'm instantiating cells in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` using `UITableViewCell`, not a custom subclass. Here is the remainder of the method:

```
PersonInfo *info = nil;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    info = [self.filteredPeopleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    info = [self.peopleList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBk.png"]];
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

cell.imageView.image = info.image;
cell.textLabel.text = info.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = info.title;

return cell;
```

The `tableView` (the "regular" one) and `searchResultsTableView` is being set as follows inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
//Set the default tableView style
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

//Set the self.searchDisplayController background stuff
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.opaque = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the code to style the `searchResultsTableView` into `searchDisplayController:willShowSearchResultsTableView:`, a method of UISearchDisplayDelegate, takes care of this.